# edit, delete, upload, on 000webhost sometimes work sometimes not php

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I host the web that I created on 000webhost.com. All went well. But there are mistakes that happen sometimes. When uploading photos, adding data to the database, or when editing data. Sometimes data is stored and changed, sometimes nothing happens. Sometimes photos uploaded, sometimes nothing happens. Sometimes the data is successfully edited, sometimes nothing happens. Why is that? What is wrong?


this is my code

```
<?php 

  include('connect.php');

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artikel");

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $judul = $_POST['judul'];
  $isi = $_POST['isi'];
  $link = $_POST['link'];
  $tanggal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $message = "Data tidak boleh kosong!";

  //Jika form nama tidak di isi
  if(empty($judul || $isi || $link)){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location = 'edit-artikel.php?id=$id';</script>";
  }
  //Jika kedua form di isi masukan data baru ke database
  else{
  $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"img/ArtPic/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");
  if ($move){
  $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `artikel` SET waktu='$tanggal', judul='$judul', isi='$isi', foto='$fileName', link='$link' WHERE id='$id'");
  //Pemrosesan telah selesai, dan kembalikan ke halaman index.php
  echo "<script>window.location = 'beranda-admin.php';</script>";
  }elseif (empty($fileName)) {
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `artikel` SET waktu='$tanggal', judul='$judul', isi='$isi', link='$link' WHERE id='$id'");
    echo "<script>window.location = 'beranda-admin.php';</script>";
  }else{
     echo "gagal bor";
  }
  }
  exit;
 ?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting and i bet `nothing happens` turn into `error happens`.

Comment: @castis how to turn on reporting?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: @tadman I do not understand using fremework. if I want to learn, maybe not now. because this is a college assignment that must be gathered as soon as possible. what if I use mysqli?

Comment: I use mysqli and work now. Hey, very nice tips. u get 2 thumbs. Haha thankyouuu. @tadman

Comment: Frameworks help you get more done, and help you learn faster because they provide good examples. They don't prevent you from digging deeper into how PHP works, or how to architect bigger applications. There's a bit more up-front learning to use one effectively, but that investment of time pays off very quickly when you start to leverage all the community code available you can plug in to solve tricky problems with pre-built solutions very quickly.

Comment: The other things frameworks do is give you a secure foundation to build off of. There's a [*lot* of threats out there](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) that you *must* defend against or your site will be exploited. There's a scary number of automated probing tools that will poke your site, test it for common vulnerabilities, and if it finds one, deploy hostile code, all automatically. Security is no longer an optional concern. It's a mandatory consideration.

Comment: can you tell me where I can learn about the framework easily? @tadman

Comment: Depends on what framework. Laravel, which is just one example, has mountains of high-quality training material like [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com) and [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/search?q=laravel). Others have their own resources.

Comment: woohoo, thanks a lot. I'll learn it later. looks like i will love it. I need to learn a lot about this, because I'm still a newbie. @tadman